# c++ vecotr with iterator can't be destroyed?

Tags: c++17

Recently I have faced a problem when the program running the memory keep increasing, and when program is closed the memory would restore normal level. Obviously, it's a memory leak. After some work, I have located the code responsible, but I don't know why? The program's work flow is simple:

1. first use lidar api to get point cloud and image data;
2. then transport to next tbb flow graph to process these data;
3. finally use open3d api to visualzie them.

In the first step, the lidar itself's api use asio to asynchronously invoke some callback function  to transport data, so I create some tbb `concurrent_queue` to store these data, and a align function to match cloud and image with timestamp. The problem is in the align function. In the function, I create a `vector<shared_ptr<open3d::..::PointCloud>>` and use iterator to store point cloud elements. However, I found when the function complete, the shared_ptr use count don't reduce . Similar but simpler example code like this:

```
std::pair<std::shared_ptr<int>, int> helper() {
    auto a = std::make_shared<int>(90);
    auto c = 100;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<int>, int>> container;
    container.reserve(5);
    auto iter = container.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        *iter = std::make_pair(a, c);
        iter++;
    }
    return *(iter-1);
 }

 int main() {
     auto b = helper();
     std::cout << "shared_ptr use count: " << std::get<0>(b).use_count() << std::endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

Ubuntu 20.04 + gcc 9.4, the print result is `shared_ptr use count: 4`.
Why the vector can't be auto destroyed when function is completed? Hope someone kindly explain this problem.

Comment: `container.reserve(5);` reserves space in a container but does not resize it, the vector is still empty. Everything you do with the iterator after that is undefined behavior. I assume that since the vector believes it is empty it doesn't destroy anything when it goes out of scope.

Comment: yes, as you assumed, I tried print the vector size after the for loop, and find the size is 0   
 -_-.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Retired Ninja! The root of the problem is `vector.reserve` just reserve capacity not physical space. So the vector space after reserve is 0. The following iterator operation is assumed point to some undifined memory. While the result can be transport to main function with no value error, the shared_ptr use count can't reduce to 1 after function call.

To solve the problem, One can just modify the `reserve` to `resize`, which can change physical space of the vector and iterator point to defined memory space. Or avoid use iterator, just use `push_back` and return `back()`.